# Connect my spring boot application to two RabbitMQs

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have two microservices that communicate with the rest of the microservices in the platform. Let's say that I have something like this:

```
--------------     --------------
|Microservice1|    |Microservice2|
|  Processor  |    |    Proxy    |----------- RabbitMQ
---------------    ---------------
      |                   |
----------------------------------
|       Internal RabbitMQ        |
----------------------------------
```

How can I configure the Spring Boot application I have for the Microservice2, that it is able to connect to two RabbitMQ instances (it can also be two virtual host in one rabbitmq). I was checking several websites and I could not find implementation to follow.

Comment: I think this can be your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960153/spring-amqp-project-with-2-queues

Comment: Hi Stephane, I think it is not exactly what I am looking for, because in that link is described how to declare two queues.