# Rabbbitmq xml configuration

Tags: xml, spring-rabbit

I am trying to understand RabbitMQ- Spring AMQP codes. I have few doubts in the case where RabbitMQ is configured in XML files.

The sender part of xml is as shown below-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" 
host="localhost" username="guest" password="guest"/>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
exchange="tpExchange"/> 
</beans>
```

The sender code is as shown below-

```
public class SpringAMQPRabbitSender {
    private final static String SENDER_XML = "springamqp-rabbit-sender-         context.xml";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate = (AmqpTemplate)(new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(SENDER_XML)).getBean("amqpTemplate");
  int messagCount = 0;
  while (messagCount < 10){
    amqpTemplate.convertAndSend("tp.routingkey.1", "Message # " + messagCount++);
  }
  System.out.println( messagCount + " message(s) sent successfully.");
}
```

The receiver xml part is as shown

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" 
          username="guest" password="guest"/>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
<rabbit:queue id ="tpQueue"/>

<rabbit:topic-exchange id="tpExchange" name="tpExchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="tpQueue" pattern="tp.routingkey.1">
        </rabbit:binding>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>

<bean id="asyncListener" class="com.tp.spring_amqp_rabbitmq.SpringAMQPRabbitAyncListener"/>

<rabbit:listener-container id="myListenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="asyncListener" queue-names="tpQueue"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>

</beans>
```

The argument to convertAndSend() in sender code gives the routing key used by sender and the message to be sent. But what exchange is it being sent to??
My doubts are :

1. Which exchange is used by sender to send the message? Is it the one specified in  tag in xml file?
2. If yes, then in tag -   exchange = "tpExchange" specifies the name of the exchange or the id of the exchange?
3. In the tag -  in receiver xml, is "tpQueue" the id of the queue or name of the queue?

4.Also, since the tag - in receiver xml has no name, is this code using anonymous queues??

Please help. Looked for it in few websites...couldn't get much info.
Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody please help me understand this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. In the `<template/>` element; the exchange name is needed, not the id.
3. `<rabbit:queue id ="tpQueue"/>`

Since the queue has no name, an auto-delete anonymous queue is used.

In the `<listener/>` element, you must refer to such queues with the `queues` attribute, not the the `queue-names` attribute. If you want to use the `queue-names` attribute you must give the queue a name.

Refer to the XSD documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was of great help:)

Comment: But I came across few codes where they are using "queues" in the listener but it is referring to queue name as <rabbit : queue > tag had no id.

Comment: For eg: <rabbit:queue name="testQueue2" durable="true"/>

Comment: <rabbit:listener ref="messageListener" method="handleIncoming" queues="testQueue2"/>

Comment: Is this the correct way, i.e using "queues" in listener which contains the queue name as its attribute value

Comment: In earlier versions of the framework, the name was always registered as an alias for the bean, allowing it to be used where bean references were needed; this caused other problems (and confusion). [Details here if you want to read the history](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-617). We still register the name as an alias if there's no id, so it can be used, but I prefer to always reference them by id and use the name where the name is needed.

Comment: Thank You so much:) helped a lot.

Comment: I came across RabbitMQ xml configuration code where the "exchange" attribute in <rabbit: template> tag refers to exchange id -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960153/spring-amqp-project-with-2-queues . It is little confusing now as to whether the "exchange" attribute in <rabbit: template> element refers to exchange name or exchange id.